# Monitor and Catch URLs opened by a Node.js app with Node.js code

Tags: node.js, https, proxy, fiddler, sniffing

I have a closed-source Node.js app that opens URLs at random intervals when certain conditions are met. I want to catch these URLs opened by the app with some Node.js code so that I can then use them to do other stuff in real time.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How to set proxy settings in Node.js can be found easily when searching the web.

Comment: So far I tryed to use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/https-localhost for setting up the HTTPS proxy, but then I get invalid certificate when I set it up in Chrome.

Comment: You have added the tag "Fiddler" why don't use leave HTTPS interception to Fiddler? You just have to set Fiddler as proxy in Node.js and install the Fiddler root-CA certificate so that it is trusted by Node.js.